# Generic list of Objects, passed through a HTML text writer class to output html. Now trying to implement paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, paging

I have a list of objects which have been taken form a stored procedure. I then take this list pass it through a method I created which wraps it in HTML and then out puts to the webform.

I'm looking to create paging for this list. I have stored the list in a session and have two buttons ( next and previous ) I'm using LINQ to skip and take form the list on each button click.

**Button Click**

```
protected void lnkNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListOfAdvertAndUsers = (List<Advert_User>)Session["list"];

    var list = from item in ListOfAdvertAndUsers select item;

    var pgNo = 1;
    var pgRec = 6;

    list = list.Skip(pgRec * pgNo).Take(pgRec).ToList();

    ListOfAdvertAndUsers = list.ToList();

    PopulateData(ListOfAdvertAndUsers);
}
```

Comment: What is the question?  I note that you're hard coding the page number and size in the event handler, so clicking "Next" really does nothing.

Comment: Also you're creating queries and lists, overwriting them, and not storing anything back to the session.  I think you can simplify the code significantly and then maybe your problem will become more apparent.

Comment: @DStanley - What should I do? I'm looking for the next button to take X items out of the list, when the use hits the it again, it will take another X items out of the list.

Comment: You don't need to remove items from the list - just increment your "page number" that is used in the "skip" call.  Otherwise there's no way to go "back" in the list.

Comment: @DStanley - I had an un-ordered list with list items as page numbers, but I decide against it, should I go back to that instead?

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused now.  Maybe you should do some more research on paging before jumping to solutions.  You need some sort of consistent order to do paging or you'll end up with random items on each "page".

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to make a comment so I will just post my comments as an answer.

I presume that you are using Asp.Net WebForms, so how are you outputting the final html, Response.Write or setting Text on a Literal?

But if you are using WebForms, would it not be easier to use some of the builtin Controls. I don´t exactly know how your data looks like, but maybe a GridView would be a good solution as it has builtin support for paging. Here is an example from MS on how it can be used: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/presenting-and-managing-data/model-binding/sorting-paging-and-filtering-data

Comment: Yes I'm using Asp.Net WebForms. The final output looks like this - http://imgur.com/KbaG9EB I was the understanding the gridview could not give the same affect. 

And the Html Writer class looks like this - http://pastebin.com/5UU1jFbp

So I'm looking to take the list, take x amount out, skip x amount on each button click. then pass the list of the html text writer method.

Comment: I see. I would say if you are sticking to a server side solution, I would use some of the builtin Controls to handle your specific scenario. A control like the ListView seems to be a good fit. It has also support for built in paging, and can provide you complete control over the html markup generated. To get going it just requires a DataSource (I would expect that you could use a Objectdatasource, as you do some after processing of you data, after you read it out through your SP. ), and that you overwrite the ItemTemplate and LayoutTemplate. Try using the Designer as it can guide you.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but you're overwriting queries and lists, which seem to convolute the code unnecessarily.  Your method could be simplified to:

```
protected void lnkNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListOfAdvertAndUsers = (List<Advert_User>)Session["list"];

    var pgNo = 1;  // don't you need to increment the page number somewhere?
    var pgRec = 6; // should this be defined somewhere other than this method?

    var page = ListOfAdvertAndUsers.Skip(pgRec * pgNo).Take(pgRec);

    PopulateData(page);
}
```

Perhaps that will help you determine what the real problem is...